# Java DAO object SQLexception

Tags: java, mysql, sqlexception

New to Java and MySQL.

Am using a DAO object to query a table, running via Eclipse. MySQL edited via Workbench. table exists and Getting the following exceptions:

```
SELECT movie_name, release_dd, release_mm, release_yyyy, duration, language, director, genre, actor_1, actor_2 FROM movie_details_table WHERE movie_name = 'Piku'

java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:787)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5244)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5167)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5206)
at com.library.model.MovieDAO.getMovieDetails(MovieDAO.java:41)
at com.library.model.MovieDetTest.main(MovieDetTest.java:18)
```

MovieDAO class:

```
package com.library.model;


import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import com.library.model.beans.*;

public class MovieDAO {

private static final String DB_URL = 
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost/planner";

//  Database credentials
private static final String USER = "Sudipto";
private static final String PASS = "sudi85";

public MovieDetails getMovieDetails(String inputMov) throws     
SQLException {

MovieDetails movieDetails = new MovieDetails();

    try {

        //Open a connection
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
                      (DB_URL,USER,PASS);

       //Create and execute query
       String queryString = "SELECT movie_name, release_dd, release_mm, release_yyyy, duration, language, director, genre, actor_1, actor_2 FROM movie_details_table WHERE movie_name = '" + inputMov + "'";

       System.out.println(queryString);

       PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement
    (queryString);



       ResultSet rsMovieDetails = statement.executeQuery();

       movieDetails.setMovieName(rsMovieDetails.getString
       ("movie_name"));
       movieDetails.setReleaseDate
      (rsMovieDetails.getInt ("release_dd"), rsMovieDetails.getInt ("release_mm"), rsMovieDetails.getInt ("release_yyyy"));
       movieDetails.setDuration(rsMovieDetails.getInt
       ("duration"));
       movieDetails.setLanguage(rsMovieDetails.getString
       ("language"));
       movieDetails.setDirector(rsMovieDetails.getString
       ("director"));
       movieDetails.setGenre(rsMovieDetails.getString
       ("genre"));
       movieDetails.setActor1(rsMovieDetails.getString
       ("actor_1"));
       movieDetails.setActor2(rsMovieDetails.getString
       ("actor_2"));

      }

      catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }

  return movieDetails;

}

}
```

Have the following error log in MySQL workbench:

```
2015-05-31T15:04:36, 27, Note, Aborted connection 27 to db: 'planner' user: 'Sudipto' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

Can anyone please suggest how and what I need to fix?

Comment: Updated both the MovieDAO class and the MySQL error log in the query. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: add `rsMovieDetails.next()` before `movieDetails.setMovieName()`

Comment: Brilliant. I thought a single record wouldn't need a next(). Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rsMovieDetails.next() to retrive details. Like rs.next() is used in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html. 
rs.next() shifts the cursor to the next row of the result set from the database and returns true if there is any row, otherwise returns false. If row is present then u should retrieve the data